# Understanding MOSFET switching

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, switching

I have got an optocoupler to isolate two circuits. One signal would be trasmitted to the other side using a MOSFET and a optocoupler. The scheme is similar to this:

[image]

The Vin voltage signal is a 3.3v digital signal. I don't fully understand the requirements for the MOSFET to switch properly (and work properly, in general). In the datasheet I can read the following:

[image]

So, if VGS max is 1.6V and I am controlling the MOSFET with a 3.3V digital signal it will burn it, right?

EDITED: added for the answer:

[image]

Comment: no, it is not right. this max Vgs given due to some technological differences. absolute parameters is in  table5.

Comment: Ok, in the limiting values table Vgs min and max are -20 and 20V, so there is no problem. But... with values bigger than 1.1 it will switch, being the minimum 0.48V for that.

Comment: 3.3V will be OK.

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Can I ask what's the origin of Vin?  Have you considered driving the optocoupler LED directly from that?

Comment: @jonathanjo Its a GPIO from a MCU. I did not consider that. I guess it's totally valid.

Comment: @user263983 ok, but, why? Because 3.3V > 0.48V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The figure you've quoted, \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ is not a maximum, it is the potential difference between gate G and source S of the MOSFET necessary to *just begin* switching it on. From the [BSS184 datasheet](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BSS138BK.pdf) we know that this "threshold" of channel conduction will never be more than 1.6V, and never less than 0.48V. However, more typically for this device, the value will be 1.1V

This information comes from the "characteristics" table on page 6, a section of the datasheet, more commonly called "electrical characteristics" in most other datasheets. If you wish to know what conditions will actually damage the device, you should usually refer to the section entitled "limiting values" on page 3, a table usually called "absolute maximum ratings" by other manufacturers. In that table you find this:

[image]

Here are listed the extremes of potential difference \$V_{GS}\$ between gate and source that the transistor is guaranteed to tolerate without damage. The minimum is −20V, telling you that you must never allow the gate to become more than 20V *more negative* than the source. For instance, if you know the source potential to be \$V_S=+5V\$, then the gate cannot fall further in potential than \$V_G=-15V\$. Similarly, the "maximum" figure of +20V tells you that you mustn't ever permit the gate to rise further than 20V *more positive* than the source, so if \$V_S=+5V\$ then you must ensure \$V_G \le +25V\$.

In your circuit the arithmetic is made very easy, because the transistor's source terminal is held at 0V, by being tied to ground. That means you can safely apply any gate potential between these two values:

$$ V_{G(MIN)} = V_S - 20V = 0V - 20V = -20V $$
$$ V_{G(MAX)} = V_S +20V = 0V + 20V = +20V $$

Since your gate signal will be either 0V or +3.3V, you don't need to worry.

However, this doesn't answer your concerns about what gate potential is necessary to turn the MOSFET on, and light that opto-isolator's LED. For that we turn to the first parameter we mentioned, \$V_{GS(TH)}\$. As I said, this is the potential difference \$V_G - V_S\$ that must be present for this device's channel (between drain and source) to *start* to become conductive. It's not enough to switch the transistor *fully* on, for that you will require significantly greater \$V_{GS}\$.

Again, since you've grounded the source, so \$V_S=0V\$, the math is trivial; when the digital input signal is low, at 0V, then gate potential is \$V_G=0V\$. Therefore:

$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S = 0V - 0V = 0V $$

This value \$V_{GS}=0V\$ is significantly below the threshold of \$V_{GS(TH)}=+1.1V\$, and will ensure that the MOSFET is firmly *off*, channel resistance is as high as it can possibly be, and no current will flow.

Strictly speaking, you should stay below the lower value for \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ shown in the datasheet, which is \$V_{GS(TH)}=+0.48V\$, since you might be unlucky enough to have an outlier device. Similarly, when determining what \$V_{GS}\$ will switch the transistor on, we would refer to the upper limit \$V_{GS(TH)}=+1.6V\$, just in case our particular device is atypical.

When the digital input is +3.3V above ground, so that \$V_G=+3.3V\$, then:

$$ V_{GS} = V_G - V_S = +3.3V - 0V = +3.3V $$

Remembering that we will require \$V_{GS}\$ to be significantly greater than \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ to turn on the transistor ("just conducting" is not sufficient, we want maximum, or near maximum conductance), it's clear that 3.3V is indeed well above that threshold. Anyone familiar with MOSFETs in such low power scenarios as this wouldn't need convincing, and would be happy with that.

Just for completeness, though, here's one way you can determine for sure whether the MOSFET's channel will be sufficiently conductive. Start by figuring out what current would be flowing if the MOSFET were perfectly conductive. In this scenario, that condition would be represented by replacing the MOSFET with a short circuit, as if it were completely "on" (saturated):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1AwR8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We want to know roughly what current will flow when the transistor is fully switched on, assuming that in this state it has zero channel resistance, \$R_{DS} = 0\Omega\$. It won't be zero, but it will be close to that, and we only require a ballpark figure for now. Let's assume, then that \$R_{DS}\$ doesn't exist, it's like a wire short-circuit.

From the [opto-isolator datasheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83446/vom617a.pdf), we can find \$V_F\$, the voltage across its LED when lit:

$$ V_F = 1.1V $$

Given that the supply is +3.3V, Kirchhoff's voltage law can tell us \$V_1\$ across resistor R1:

$$ V_1 = +3.3V - V_F = +2.2V $$

By Ohm's law, the current \$I_D\$ through R1, the LED and the MOSFET channel will be:

$$ I_D \approx \frac{V_1}{R_1} \approx \frac{+2.2V}{390\Omega} \approx 5.6mA $$

We refer to graphs in the MOSFET datasheet that will reveal the true \$R_{DS}\$, the channel resistance between drain and source, given \$V_{GS} = +3.3V\$ and current \$I_D=5.6mA\$. Different datasheets present these data in different ways. The graph in this particular datasheet that interests us is figure 8 on page 7:

[image]

There isn't a plot for \$V_{GS}=3.3V\$, but we can see that it will lie somewhere between plots (4) and (5) on that graph. Drain current \$I_D=5.6mA\$, which is way to the left, perhaps even smaller than the graph shows. It's pretty clear that our MOSFET will have a drain-to-source resistance \$R_{DS}\$ well under 2Ω.

The graph shows typical behaviour, but even if we got a very bad MOSFET, it wouldn't be so bad as to push \$R_{DS}\$ very far above 2Ω. This resistance will of course reduce drain (and LED) current a tiny amount, but it will be negligible in this application. We can conclude that \$V_{GS}=+3.3V\$ is easily sufficient to fully light that LED, and won't damage the MOSFET at all.

Comment: This is a truly AWESOME answer. Thanks a lot for your time and really good explanation. For the last part, I think I will use the 3.3V signal to power the LED directly, deleting the MOSFET from the scheme, but now, my understanding on this topic is clear. There is something about the Rds you mentioned that worries me. If I switch another MOSFET (in other scheme) with my VOUT (optocoupler's output) I will hace a parallel resistor with my pulldown (1k66 and Rds=2 ohm), so the current consumtion would be really high: around 2.5A in the MOSFET (?). Itotal = 5V/(1k69||2). Ipulldown = 3mA. Irds=2.5A

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics I can't see that scenario in my head. Surely \$V_{OUT}\$ will be driving another MOSFET gate, which would draw negligible current from \$V_{OUT}\$. The gate is entirely disconnected from drain and source and the \$R_{DS}\$ between them. If that were not so, your 3.3V digital input to Q? would suffer the same trouble.

Comment: I have edited the question in order to add the new design: 3.3 power supply has been sustituted with, directly, Vin (3.3 digital input from a MCU's GPIO). It seems to be the same. Appart from that, my last question was related to how to choose the value for the pulldown resistor (1k69 in the picture), being worry about power consumption: that pulldown will be in parallel with whatever I connect to Vout (another MOSFET in this case). It is true that Rds is independent. I did not think about that. Thanks

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics The CTR of the opto-isolator is 100% with LED current of 5mA, so its transistor can pass up to 5mA. In the emitter-follower configuration you have it, output will be +4.3V max, so with the 1.7kΩ emitter resistor, current in that resistor will be \$\frac{4.3V}{1.7kΩ}=2.5mA\$, within the limits. Only you can know if that's OK. The question is what will you be connecting to \$V_{OUT}\$, and will it source or sink current?

Comment: That calculation would be OK for calculating power dissipation on the pulldown, my question was more in the sense of the importance of that resistor when I connect a MOSFET to VOUT. MOSFETs has a capacitance, that "capacitor" will load with the current coming from VOUT, so it may affect on/off times, I guess... So, How do I calculate the value of the pulldown when I am connecting the output of the circuit to a MOSFET in order to swich it on or off. Which are the parameters (appart from power consumption in the resistor) that I have to consider. I guess it's not the same 1k than 5k or than 10k

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Yes that resistance will surely slow down gate discharging. If you had 1nF of gate capacitance, to discharge through 1kΩ-ish, you can expect a gate fall time of the order of \$1nF \times 1kΩ=1\mu s\$. However, it won't rise much faster than that either, since transistor current is limited by the CTR of the opto-isolator, to about 5mA, which would produce a similar rise time. And that same current limit means you can't really go under \$\frac{5V}{5mA}=1kΩ\$.

Comment: Oh, ok. But I could get a higher CTR. In the datasheet I have seen values bigger than 100%. By the way, the time constant is capacitance * resistances, but, you said "would produce a similar rise time", which is the formula for charging or discharging just with current to know that? Thanks thanks thanks for your time

Comment: @DevelopingElectronics Constant current \$I\$ charging: \$t\approx\frac{CV}{I}\$. It's *very* approximate, because current won't be constant, but you can get a rough idea. You should design based on worst case CTR, but you can increase the current in the LED, to get a commensurate increase in output collector current. I think your device can handle up to 60mA for the LED, but you should verify that. And there's no way a GPIO can sink that, so maybe back to the original transistor controlling LED current idea?